# Who exactly are the "security research community"?

Tags: discussion

On the ["Security"](https://stackexchange.com/about/security) page - under the "Hall of Fame" section - it mentions a "security research community", who are they?

I've gone through the ["Team"](https://stackexchange.com/about/security) page, the closest I found that might be security related were the internal support engineers, but I wouldn't exactly call them the "security research community". I've also had a quick search of Meta Stack Exchange, again no results.

Or, is this information, you know, [*classified*](https://camo.githubusercontent.com/c365427633144624f9f72a220c144b9112696137/687474703a2f2f662e636c2e6c792f6974656d732f32373234326431623137317431633253335a306e2f677265672e676966).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They are ***regular*** users, who have spotted ***serious*** security issues with SE code. They notified SE about the issues, and possibly even tips on how to fix them. SE does not discuss what the security issues were, for security reasons, and possibly not wanting to draw attention to the security issues they had in the past.

Comment: Interesting, so they just used "security research community" to anonymise these users, I guess.

Comment: @Sam I think it's more that it's not a particular set of users, but the community of people who help SO/SE by looking into security issues.

Comment: @Sam: No, they used it to represent a group of users, just like I would to discuss "the community in which I live" or "the community of SO readers"; it's the group of users that are familiar with the topic of security research.

Comment: Oh right, thanks for explaining. The wording they used gave me the impression they were an external community of white hats or something.